# Trials to claim a throne

Tags: character-development

My novel is about a girl who is the heir to the throne of Helheim, the Norse world of the dead,  but in order to claim the throne she has to pass a 3 part trial. I’m having a hard time coming up with what the trials should be. The first trial will be to gain the trust of the dog that guards the gates to Helheim.  Should the next step in the trial be something related to deciding someone’s fate as they enter Helheim? Since that’s ultimately what she will be doing when she rules.

Comment: Hi Maranda, welcome to our site. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close your question as off-topic. The [Help page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Questions asking what to write about [are not allowed].... We're looking to avoid questions where the intent is to generate ideas." For further guidance, take the Writing **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Maranda.  We would love to see more questions about your novel or other writing in the future, as well as any answers you want to share.  Unfortunately, this particular question is off topic here because you're asking us for ideas on what to write.  Please stick around and hopefully we'll see more from you.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Maranda*! I am afraid we can't help you write your novel here. This site is dedicated to providing general questions and answers that also be useful to future readers readers, which a discussion about what your story should be about wouldn't be. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site, specifically [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Have fun on the site and good luck with your project!

Comment: After that warm triple welcome, a small comment from me: if you don't have a good idea for the three trials, maybe it's not the best idea for you to explore? It's not the most novel idea anyway, and I'm sure you can come up with something that's more interesting to you personally, so that you won't feel the need to ask others what to write!

Comment: @Spectrosaurus That's such an interesting thought that I took the liberty of turning it into a question: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44203/is-wanting-to-ask-what-to-write-an-indication-that-you-need-to-change-your-story